# Studies about personal message from company leadership?

Tags: copywriting, login, landing-page

I have a wireframe that I have created for a private business portal. The site is for private testing groups of experimental equipment.

Since most users will be volunteers, I was wondering if a personal message from the leadership might further establish rapport. Ideally they would come back often and spend more time on the site. I put that around the link to the login because I wanted returning users to feel appreciated.

[image: homepage]

Answer (score 1):

Studies have shown that *emotional design* is a powerful factor in creating rapport with users. Making the site friendlier around the login process would help to strengthen this link.

There is some general information here - http://uxdesign.smashingmagazine.com/2012/07/18/the-personality-layer/

And an interesting case study here - http://blog.usabilla.com/case-study-how-slugbooks-rebranded-through-emotional-design/

Also, an interesting look at the subject by Don Norman here - http://www.jnd.org/dn.mss/emotional_desig.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, these links are excellent resources and I will definitely begin to implement. What do you think about the context though, about a personal message from company leadership?